# Calculate length between marginpar and page edge

Tags: geometry, latex3

This is about calculating and saving a `LaTeX3` dim to pass as a parameter when loading a package. If it matters I'm using

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (MiKTeX 22.3)
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 3
geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
```

I have two problems:

1. can't calculate the correct length from the `geometry` package

   - the length from the outer edge of the `marginpar` to the outer edge of the paper
2. can't make `LaTeX3` put the length in the correct form as a parameter to a package

   - (`Undefined control sequence <argument> width={\use_dim:N \l__calculated_width_dim}`)

```latex
\usepackage[width={\dim_use:N \l__calculated_width_dim}]{aPackage}
```

#### MWE (broken)

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    top=25mm,
    bottom=25mm,
    inner=25mm,
    textwidth=100mm,
    marginparsep=10mm,
    marginparwidth=40mm
  }
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
% \dim_show:n { \Gm@layoutwidth }
% \dim_show:n { \Gm@layouthoffset }
\dim_new:N \l__calculated_width_dim
\dim_set:Nn \l__calculated_width_dim
  {
    \pagewidth - \Gm@layoutwidth - \Gm@layouthoffset
  }
% \dim_show:n { \l__calculated_width_dim }
\makeatother

\usepackage[width={\use_dim:N \l__calculated_width_dim}]{aPackage}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Text.
\end{document}
```

I know it's probably possible to calculate the length on the fly as part of the `\usepackage` command. I thought it useful to save the length for reuse.

I want the length from the outer edge of the `marginpar` to outer edge of the paper. Looking at the [`geometry`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package documentation page 7 looks like the calculation should be `\pagewidth - \layoutwidth - \layouthoffset`.

`\dim_show:n { \pagewidth }` shows the correct width of the paper in pt.

`\dim_show:n { \layoutwidth }` causes a missing number error.

A bit of digging in `geometry` made me try

```latex
\makeatletter
\dim_show:n { \Gm@layoutwidth }
\dim_show:n { \Gm@layouthoffset }
\makeatother
```

which works but `\Gm@layoutwidth` gives me the same size as `\pagewidth` and `\Gm@layouthoffset` is 0.0pt.

I tried passing the page dimensions as parameters to `geometry` at load time

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[
    top=25mm,
    bottom=25mm,
    inner=25mm,
    textwidth=100mm,
    marginparsep=10mm,
    marginparwidth=40mm
  ]{geometry}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\dim_show:n { \Gm@layoutwidth }
\dim_show:n { \Gm@layouthoffset }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Text.
\end{document}
```

And I tried no parameters and calling `\geometry`

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\geometry{
    top=25mm,
    bottom=25mm,
    inner=25mm,
    textwidth=100mm,
    marginparsep=10mm,
    marginparwidth=40mm
  }
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\dim_show:n { \Gm@layoutwidth }
\dim_show:n { \Gm@layouthoffset }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Text.
\end{document}
```

Both have the same effect. `\Gm@layoutwidth` is always the same as `\paperwidth` and `\Gm@layouthoffset` is always 0.0pt.

Comment: I don't speak Klingon, but `\dimexpr \paperwidth-1in-\oddsidemargin-\textwidth-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth\relax` should do the trick (for odd pages).

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo. Part of this is that I want to learn LaTeX3. What's the 1in for in your calculation? I forgot to make it clear in my question that the page dimensions will differ per document.

Comment: @Doc Your question is a bit long... and misses the essential bit: what is `aPackage`, or if it's a theoretical package, what are the precise constraints? The length could be passed explicitly (e.g., `3cm`) or as a single token like a `\dimendef` or `\skipdef` token. Apart from that, John's formula looks good to me, and I believe your idea of using `geometry`'s `\layoutwidth` etc. is a dead end. By default, “the layout size defaults to
the same size as the paper”, hence your final observation. TeX's origin for layout is (1in,1in) counted from the top left corner of the paper, hence the `1in`.

Comment: Since even and odd pages can differ in geometry (due to `\evensidemargin` and `\oddsidemargin`), what *precisely* do you want to pass as `width` to your theoretical package?

Comment: Thanks @frougon Sorry, the question is long but it starts by saying what I want is "the length from the outer edge of the marginpar to the outer edge of the paper". I don't care about asymmetry in pages yet. Right now it's for the `thumbs` package `\usepackage[width=2cm]{thumbs}' I made it a generic package in the question to widen utility to others. The actual length needs calculating depending on a document's page layout which will vary per document. I expect to need the length elsewhere later in the same document. I also want to learn how to use `dim`s correctly in LaTeX3.

Comment: The 1in is built into the original TeX engine as the default top and left margin.  (Printers used to need large margins.)   It has been left in for backward compatibility.  To compensate, \topmargin and \oddsidemargin are often negative.

Comment: Thank @JohnKormylo. I must have missed the part in the `geometry` manual about the layout width. I was mostly looking at the pictures. I didn't know that about compensation using negative margins. I always thought books were printed on larger paper and then physically cropped.

Comment: What, and waste all that paper?  The covers are printed on larger sheets and cut down in order to push the images to the edge.  The geometry package hides the 1in, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, the “layout” parameters in `geometry` are used to make it easy to print, e.g., an A5 layout on A4 paper. Given that the `geometry` manual says:

> By default, “the layout size defaults to the same size as the paper”

this would explain why you found that

> `\Gm@layoutwidth` is always the same as `\paperwidth` and `\Gm@layouthoffset` is always 0.0pt.

So, I think it's best to stick with the LaTeX standard lengths for page layout, [as proposed by John
Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649702/calculate-length-between-marginpar-and-page-edge?noredirect=1#comment1619313_649702).

## LaTeX2e solution

Using John's idea, here is a first solution in LaTeX2e style. This uses `\oddsidemargin`, therefore is *a priori* correct only for odd pages—unless even pages have the same layout, of course. The `showframe` option we pass to `geometry` here shows the limits of the various page elements, esp. the margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{
    top=25mm,
    bottom=25mm,
    inner=25mm,
    textwidth=100mm,
    marginparsep=10mm,
    marginparwidth=40mm,
}

\newlength{\remainingWidth}
\setlength{\remainingWidth}{%
  \dimexpr \paperwidth - 1in -\oddsidemargin - \textwidth -
           \marginparsep - \marginparwidth \relax % or \dimeval{...} (recent)
}

% Actually, \usepackage[width=\remainingWidth]{thumbs} also works, presumably
% because what is really expected after 'width=' is a ⟨dimen⟩. That is why I wrote
% in the comments that a very precise specificiation of the interface of the
% external package is important.
\begingroup
\edef\tmp{\endgroup
  \noexpand\usepackage[width=\the\remainingWidth]{thumbs}%
}\tmp

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\addthumb{A title}{1}{white}{blue!70}%
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

## `expl3`-based solution

Since you are explicitly asking for it, here is an `expl3` way of doing the length computation and passing the `width=value` to the package of your choice. That being said, I don't think this brings us much here.

I take care of doing the `\usepackage` call after `\ExplSyntaxOff` because it reads external files and I'm not sure it would reset the category codes as expected in standard LaTeX2e if called under `\ExplSyntaxOn` régime.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{
    top=25mm,
    bottom=25mm,
    inner=25mm,
    textwidth=100mm,
    marginparsep=10mm,
    marginparwidth=40mm,
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_new:N \l_octal_remaining_width_dim

\dim_set:Nn \l_octal_remaining_width_dim
  {
    \paperwidth - 1in - \oddsidemargin - \textwidth -
    \marginparsep - \marginparwidth
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \octal_pass_kv_opt_to_pkg:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \PassOptionsToPackage { #1 = #2 } {#3}
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \octal_pass_kv_opt_to_pkg:nnn { nV }

\octal_pass_kv_opt_to_pkg:nVn { width } \l_octal_remaining_width_dim { thumbs }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{thumbs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\addthumb{A title}{1}{white}{blue!70}%
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\end{document}
```

Same output as above.

Note that `width=` and the package name `thumbs` have the same category codes regardless of whether they are entered before or after `\ExplSyntaxOn`, therefore our use of `\octal_pass_kv_opt_to_pkg:nVn` is guaranteed to pass the option to `thumbs` with the same catcodes as if done from `\usepackage` or `\PassOptionsToPackage` under the standard category code régime.

The `V` in variant `\octal_pass_kv_opt_to_pkg:nVn` passes the *value* of `dim` variable `\l_octal_remaining_width_dim` as second argument to the base form `\octal_pass_kv_opt_to_pkg:nnn`. This is equivalent to passing the result of the expansion of `\the\remainingWidth` (which we did using `\edef`) in the first method.

For other uses, if there is a risk of having inappropriate category codes (option names containing `_`, `:` or `~`...), you would simply create a wrapper or alias that does something analogous to `\octal_pass_kv_opt_to_pkg:nVn { width } \l_octal_remaining_width_dim { thumbs }` and call it *after* `\ExplSyntaxOff`. For instance, with the same definition of `\octal_pass_kv_opt_to_pkg:nnn`, you could do:

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \octal_pass_kv_opt_to_pkg:nnn { nv }
\cs_new_eq:NN \myPassKvOptToPkg \octal_pass_kv_opt_to_pkg:nvn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\myPassKvOptToPkg{width}{l_octal_remaining_width_dim}{thumbs}

\usepackage{thumbs}
```

in which case the option name `width` as well as the package name `thumbs` would be tokenized under the standard LaTeX category code régime.

Comment: Thanks @frougon this is exactly what I want. It still works when I change the widths of text and marginpar and separator. I know the `expl3` version isn't necessarily shorter or clearer but I won't learn the language by avoiding it. I haven't seen `\octal` before. Thank you for your detailed answer with alternatives.

Comment: `\octal_` is a supposedly unique prefix I chose because of your username. Normally, it should identify “the package” (or module in `expl3` talk). But code doesn't necessarily belongs to a package → what is important is to choose it unique enough that it won't clash with other people's code (TeX has no namespaces!).

Comment: The tricky part when interfacing `expl3` code with the rest of LaTeX is often catcode issues, esp. when you're starting with `expl3`, hence my insistance on the subject, especially since we are writing stuff for `\usepackage` which is expected to be executed under the standard catcode régime...